# How does DFSR work out costs to other sites?

Tags: active-directory, dfs, dfs-r

We have 4 sites - two of which host DFS servers.

```
Site A - DFS Server #1 (namespace member, replication group)
Site B - DFS Server #2 (namespace member, replication group)
Site C - No servers, just PCs.
Site D - No servers, just PCs.
```

By default, clients who access the namespace are referred to the DFS server in their local site. i.e. a PC in `Site A` will get `DFS Server #1` as their referral.

However, a client PC in Site C has no local DFS server.

From a networking perspective, it is cheaper to go to `Site A` to access the data. But there are no DCs, no servers, therefore no site links, thus no costs. How does DFS work out site costs.

How can I force it to use `Site A` instead of `Site B`. Do I need to create AD site links from `Site C to Site A` with a cheaper cost than `Site C to Site B` (even though there are no DCs?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to add the subnets for sites C and D in ADS&S and associate them with site A.

Clients in sites C and D will then have affinity with site A and will authenticate with the DC's in site A and will get DFS referrals for the DFS servers in site A.

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I encountered this today as well.  Contrary to what was assumed, you actually *can* set up costs for a site that doesn't have a DC.  I do this for some remote sites which are within our enterprise network, but not within my local control.  In my case, site C includes our VPN users, and I was using it to steer them to a specific DFS server that has more bandwidth.

- Keep sites C and D with appropriate subnets as separate sites to match the topology of your network.
- Create a two new site links that include sites A and C in one, and sites A and D in the other.
- Set the cost of the new site links lower than your default site link, assuming you have one (the one that includes A, B, C, and D).

This sets a preferred path for sites C and D.  Wait for DFS changes to replicate, or speed things along with the appropriate `repadmin /syncall` and `dfsutil /pktflush` commands.